# Unable to load config data to springboot application from mounted volume in kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, shell, kubernetes, configuration

I have springboot application and I am trying to load additional configuration from a volume mounted location /tmp/secret-config.yaml and getting below error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from '/tmp/secret-config.yaml'

I do not want to use configmap or secrets for this. It's a simple json file which I am trying to load.

I am trying to pass it like this from shell script.
java -jar /opt/app.jar --spring.config.additional-location=/tmp/secret-config.yaml

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: did you check that the yaml file is in fact availble in the container? please show your YAML manifests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to verify the volume mount of the file inside your pod.
You can verify it with the following commands:

```
kubectl exec -it <podName> -- cat /tmp/secret-config.yaml

kubectl exec -it <podName> -- ls /tmp
```

In addition, the volume mount configuration in your yaml file would be interesting. Did you specify a `mountPath`  for the `volumeMount` in your pod configuration?
You can also check the mountPath with the following command:

```
# for a pod with a single container and only one volumeMount
kubectl get pods <podName> -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].mountPath}'
```

Comment: Hello @Jonas, I was able to solve the issue. The actual issue was the paths of the jar file and the volume mount. I should have given the absolute paths instead of relative from the home directory. But yes the above approach would have made it easier to find it. Thanks.

Comment: @mayankagarwal Glad you were able to find the issue.